# Как избавиться от превьюшки phpThumb?

Tags: php, phpthumb

Добавляю изображение через phpThumb. В течение секунды, пока страница грузится, видно такое изображение (см.ниже), а потом нормально. Как сделать так, чтобы загружалось только финальное изображение без этого сообщения? Потом, когда файл кэшируется, все работает как положено.
Когда меняешь параметр "disable_debug" на false перестает все работать

```
 $PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug']= true;
```

[Конфиг](https://yadi.sk/d/Ij5ubE89iRu8T)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Случайным образом удалось избавится от этой ошибки, но не думаю что правильно:
Изменил параметр

```
$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['cache_source_enabled']   = true;
```

Comment: Предоставьте качественный скрин!

Comment: @LevBazdyrev не получится сделать скрин качественно, PhpThumb выдает такое изображение, оно висит на экране меньше секунды. Подозреваю что это предупреждение, о том что нужно выключить дебаг или включить наоборот

Comment: вы пробовали выполнить то, что предлагается сделать на первой картинке? перевод: отредактируйте `phpThumb.config.php` и (временно) установите `$PHPTHUMB_CONFIG['disable_debug'] = false;` для того, чтобы просмотреть детали ошибки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, сейчас добавлю к вопросу конфиг